# How to control one IB custom view with mouseEntered/-Exited in another IB custom view

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nsview

I'm sorry for my incompetence, but I'm new to Cocoa, Swift, and object-oriented programming, in general. My primary sources have been Cocoa Programming for OS X (5th ed.), and Apple's jargon- and Objective-C-riddled Developer pages. But I'm here because I haven't seen (or didn't realize that I saw) anything that speaks to this problem.

I want to change the contents of one IB-created custom view, LeftView, by mouseEntered/-Exited actions in another IB-created custom view, RightView. Both are in the same window. I created a toy program to try to figure things out, but to no avail.

Here's the class definition for RightView (which is supposed to change LeftView):

```
import Cocoa

class RightView: NSView {

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        // Nothing here, for now.
    }

    override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
        window?.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true

        let options: NSTrackingAreaOptions =
            [.MouseEnteredAndExited, .ActiveAlways, .InVisibleRect]

        let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: NSRect(),
                                          options: options,
                                          owner: self,
                                          userInfo: nil)
        addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }

    override func mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        Swift.print("Mouse entered!")
        LeftView().showStuff(true)
    }
    override func mouseExited(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        Swift.print("Mouse exited!")
        LeftView().showStuff(false)
    }
}
```

And here's the class definition for LeftView (which is supposed to be changed by RightView):

```
import Cocoa

class LeftView: NSView {

    var value: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            needsDisplay = true
            Swift.print("didSet happened and needsDisplay was \(needsDisplay)")
        }
    }

    override func mouseUp(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        showStuff(true)
    }
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor()
        backgroundColor.set()
        NSBezierPath.fillRect(bounds)

        Swift.print("drawRect was called when needsDisplay was \(needsDisplay)")

        switch value {
        case true: NSColor.greenColor().set()
        case false: NSColor.redColor().set()
        }
        NSBezierPath.fillRect(NSRect(x: 40, y: 40,
            width: bounds.width - 80, height: bounds.height - 80))
    }

    func showStuff(showing: Bool) {
        Swift.print("Trying to show? \(showing)")
        value = showing
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something "completely obvious," but I'm a little dense. If you could tell me how to fix the code/xib files, I would very much appreciate it. If you could explain things like when talking to a child, I would be even more appreciative. When I take over the world (I'm not incompetent at everything), I will remember your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround that is much simpler than my prior strategy. Instead of having mouseEntered/-Exited actions in one custom view try to control what is displayed in another custom view, I simply put the mouseEntered/-Exited code into the view that I wanted to control, and then I altered the location of `rect:` in `NSTrackingArea`.

Before moving code over by for that approach, I had tried changing the `owner:` in `NSTrackingArea` to `LeftView()` and just moving over the mouseEntered/-Exited code. That generated lots of scary error messages (naive newbie talking here), so I gave up on it. It would be nice to know, though, how one can correctly assign an owner other than `self`.

In any case, any further thoughts or insights would be appreciated.